# TikZ: Easy drawing of cuboids

Tags: tikz-pgf, big-list

As a teacher, I regularly have to include cuboids in my documents, so I was looking for a way to make this as easy as possible while still keeping maximal flexibility.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So I created the following `pic` that I would want to share with the community that has already helped so many times:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

\makeatletter
\def\tikz@lib@cuboid@get#1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cuboid/#1}}

\def\tikz@lib@cuboid@setup{%
   \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vxx}%
      {\tikz@lib@cuboid@get{xscale}*cos(\tikz@lib@cuboid@get{xangle})*1cm}
   \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vxy}%
      {\tikz@lib@cuboid@get{xscale}*sin(\tikz@lib@cuboid@get{xangle})*1cm}
   \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vyx}%
      {\tikz@lib@cuboid@get{yscale}*cos(\tikz@lib@cuboid@get{yangle})*1cm}
   \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vyy}%
      {\tikz@lib@cuboid@get{yscale}*sin(\tikz@lib@cuboid@get{yangle})*1cm}
   \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vzx}%
      {\tikz@lib@cuboid@get{zscale}*cos(\tikz@lib@cuboid@get{zangle})*1cm}
   \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vzy}%
      {\tikz@lib@cuboid@get{zscale}*sin(\tikz@lib@cuboid@get{zangle})*1cm}
}

\def\tikz@lib@cuboid@draw#1--#2--#3\pgf@stop{%
    \begin{scope}[join=bevel,x={(\vxx,\vxy)},y={(\vyx,\vyy)},z={(\vzx,\vzy)}]
       % first fill the faces with global and individual style
       % then draw the grids
       \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=#1]
          \draw[cuboid/all faces,cuboid/edges,cuboid/right face] 
                (0,0) -- ++(#2,0) -- ++(0,-#3) -- ++(-#2,0) -- cycle;
          \draw[cuboid/all grids,cuboid/right grid] (0,0) grid (#2,-#3);
       \end{scope}
       \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
          \draw[cuboid/all faces,cuboid/edges,cuboid/front face] 
                (0,0) -- ++(#1,0) --  ++(0,#2) -- ++(-#1,0) -- cycle;
          \draw[cuboid/all grids,cuboid/front grid] (0,0) grid (#1,#2);
       \end{scope}
       \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=#2]
          \draw[cuboid/all faces,cuboid/edges,cuboid/top face] 
                (0,0) -- ++(#1,0) --  ++(0,-#3) -- ++(-#1,0) -- cycle;
          \draw[cuboid/all grids,cuboid/top grid] (0,0) grid (#1,-#3);
       \end{scope}
       % now, draw the hidden edges
       \draw[cuboid/hidden edges] (0,#2,-#3) -- (0,0,-#3) -- (0,0,0) 
                (0,0,-#3) -- ++(#1,0,0);
       % finally, draw the visible edges 
       \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=#1]
          \draw[cuboid/all faces,cuboid/right face,cuboid/edges,fill opacity=0] 
                (0,0) -- ++(#2,0) -- ++(0,-#3) -- ++(-#2,0) -- cycle;
       \end{scope}
       \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
          \draw[cuboid/all faces,cuboid/front face,cuboid/edges,fill opacity=0] 
                (0,0) -- ++(#1,0) --  ++(0,#2) -- ++(-#1,0) -- cycle;
       \end{scope}
       \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=#2]
          \draw[cuboid/all faces,cuboid/top face,cuboid/edges,fill opacity=0] 
                (0,0) -- ++(#1,0) --  ++(0,-#3) -- ++(-#1,0) -- cycle;
       \end{scope}
       % define the anchors: 8 vertices
       \path (0,#2,0) coordinate (-left top front)
                      coordinate (-left front top)
                      coordinate (-top left front)
                      coordinate (-top front left)
                      coordinate (-front top left)
                      coordinate (-front left top);
       \path (0,#2,-#3) coordinate (-left top rear)
                        coordinate (-left rear top)
                        coordinate (-top left rear)
                        coordinate (-top rear left)
                        coordinate (-rear top left)
                        coordinate (-rear left top);
       \path (0,0,-#3) coordinate (-left bottom rear)
                       coordinate (-left rear bottom)
                       coordinate (-bottom left rear)
                       coordinate (-bottom rear left)
                       coordinate (-rear bottom left)
                       coordinate (-rear left bottom);
       \path (0,0,0) coordinate (-left bottom front)
                     coordinate (-left front bottom)
                     coordinate (-bottom left front)
                     coordinate (-bottom front left)
                     coordinate (-front bottom left)
                     coordinate (-front left bottom);
       \path (#1,#2,0) coordinate (-right top front)
                       coordinate (-right front top)
                       coordinate (-top right front)
                       coordinate (-top front right)
                       coordinate (-front top right)
                       coordinate (-front right top);
       \path (#1,#2,-#3) coordinate (-right top rear)
                         coordinate (-right rear top)
                         coordinate (-top right rear)
                         coordinate (-top rear right)
                         coordinate (-rear top right)
                         coordinate (-rear right top);
       \path (#1,0,-#3) coordinate (-right bottom rear)
                        coordinate (-right rear bottom)
                        coordinate (-bottom right rear)
                        coordinate (-bottom rear right)
                        coordinate (-rear bottom right)
                        coordinate (-rear right bottom);
       \path (#1,0,0) coordinate (-right bottom front)
                      coordinate (-right front bottom)
                      coordinate (-bottom right front)
                      coordinate (-bottom front right)
                      coordinate (-front bottom right)
                      coordinate (-front right bottom);
       % centers of the 6 faces
       \coordinate (-left center) at (0,.5*#2,-.5*#3);
       \coordinate (-right center) at (#1,.5*#2,-.5*#3);
       \coordinate (-top center) at (.5*#1,#2,-.5*#3);
       \coordinate (-bottom center) at (.5*#1,0,-.5*#3);
       \coordinate (-front center) at (.5*#1,.5*#2,0);
       \coordinate (-rear center) at (.5*#1,.5*#2,-#3);
       % center of the cuboid
       \coordinate (-center) at (.5*#1,.5*#2,-.5*#3);
       % centers of the 12 edges
       \path (0,#2,-.5*#3) coordinate (-left top center) 
                           coordinate (-top left center);
       \path (.5*#1,#2,-#3) coordinate (-top rear center)
                            coordinate (-rear top center);
       \path (#1,#2,-.5*#3) coordinate (-right top center)
                            coordinate (-top right center);
       \path (.5*#1,#2,0) coordinate (-top front center)
                          coordinate (-front top center);
       \path (0,0,-.5*#3) coordinate (-left bottom center) 
                           coordinate (-bottom left center);
       \path (.5*#1,0,-#3) coordinate (-bottom rear center)
                            coordinate (-rear bottom center);
       \path (#1,0,-.5*#3) coordinate (-right bottom center)
                            coordinate (-bottom right center);
       \path (.5*#1,0,0) coordinate (-bottom front center)
                          coordinate (-front bottom center);
       \path (0,.5*#2,0) coordinate (-left front center) 
                           coordinate (-front left center);
       \path (0,.5*#2,-#3) coordinate (-left rear center)
                            coordinate (-rear left center);
       \path (#1,.5*#2,0) coordinate (-right front center)
                            coordinate (-front right center);
       \path (#1,.5*#2,-#3) coordinate (-right rear center)
                          coordinate (-rear right center);
    \end{scope}
}

\tikzset{
  pics/cuboid/.style = {
    setup code = \tikz@lib@cuboid@setup,
    background code = \tikz@lib@cuboid@draw#1\pgf@stop
  },
  pics/cuboid/.default={1--1--1},
  cuboid/.is family,
  cuboid,
  all faces/.style={fill=white},
  all grids/.style={draw=none},
  front face/.style={},
  front grid/.style={},
  right face/.style={},
  right grid/.style={},
  top face/.style={},
  top grid/.style={},
  edges/.style={},
  hidden edges/.style={draw=none},
  xangle/.initial=0,
  yangle/.initial=90,
  zangle/.initial=210,
  xscale/.initial=1,
  yscale/.initial=1,
  zscale/.initial=0.5
}

\newcommand{\tikzcuboidreset}{
\tikzset{cuboid,
  all faces/.style={fill=white},
  all grids/.style={draw=none},
  front face/.style={},
  front grid/.style={},
  right face/.style={},
  right grid/.style={},
  top face/.style={},
  top grid/.style={},
  edges/.style={},
  hidden edges/.style={draw=none},
  xangle=0,
  yangle=90,
  zangle=210,
  xscale=1,
  yscale=1,
  zscale=0.5
}
}

\newcommand{\tikzcuboidset}{\@ifstar\tikzcuboidset@star\tikzcuboidset@nostar} 
\newcommand{\tikzcuboidset@nostar}[1]{\tikzcuboidreset\tikzset{cuboid,#1}}
\newcommand{\tikzcuboidset@star}[1]{\tikzset{cuboid,#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \pic[ultra thick,red] at (0,0,0) {cuboid=2--2--2};

      \tikzcuboidset{hidden edges/.style={dashed}}
      \pic[thick,blue] (cuboid) at (4,0,0) {cuboid=3--3--3};
      \fill[red] (cuboid-rear left center) circle (2pt);

      \tikzcuboidset*{zangle=225}
      \pic[thick,blue] at (8,0,0) {cuboid};

      \tikzcuboidset{all grids/.style={draw=blue,thin,step=.5}}
      \pic[thin,blue] at (10,0,0) {cuboid};

     \tikzcuboidset{hidden edges/.style={dashed},front face/.style={fill=red!20},right face/.style={fill=blue!20},top face/.style={fill=green!20}}
      \pic at (9,2,0) {cuboid};

     \tikzcuboidset{hidden edges/.style={dashed,draw=white},all faces/.style={fill=black}, edges/.style={draw=white,thick}}
      \pic at (12,1,0) {cuboid=2--1--3};
   \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Which yields the results as shown below

[image]

Some notes on the usage:

- You can use `\tikzcuboidset` to configure the parameters for the following cuboids. It resets all keys and sets the keys you provide. There is a starred version `\tikzcuboidset*` that *appends* your new settings to the existing ones.
- The cuboid is drawn in several steps: first the visible edges and the faces, then the grids on those faces, then the hidden edges and finally the visible edges are redrawn. This last step is needed to make the cuboid look nice, otherwise you might have gray hidden edges that run over the visible ones.
- You can specify global styles for all faces and all grids, but also give individual styles for each face and grid and these will override the global ones. However, it is not (yet) possible to set the edges individually, as they do not belong to one face only.
- The cuboids are drawn as a parallel projection and you can configure the perspective, e.g. the angle and the scaling factor for the z axis; I sometimes use this in my coursework to show the different effects.
- The cuboids will always have their front lower left vertex at the coordinate you specify, so they extend in direction of the negative z axis. This may seem odd, but it was best for my needs, as I did not want to place them with respect to a vertex that was hidden somewhere behind.

I am, of course, always interested in any suggestions on how to improve this.

Comment: Really nice solution!

Comment: Thank you for that great template. 
I have just one proposal for modification: Change the join from bevel to round.
It looks smoother, especially at the (0,#2,0) and (#1,#2,-#3) vertices.

Comment: This is quite nice!! One question: it seems to be oblivious to the tikzpicture scale modifier. Does anyone know how to fix that? Or perhaps my expectations are off?

Comment: @tgkolda Thanks for the feedback. You need to use `transform shape` in order to scale `pics`. Check out https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351871/how-can-i-make-scaling-affect-tikz-pics-within-a-tikzpicture to read more about it.

Comment: Thank you @PhilippImhof

Answer (score 0):

I have tried making a cuboid with less coding, if it will be helpful for someone, you  can use this by doing modification as per your requirement.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0)node[left](a){A}--(3,0)node[right](b){B}--(3.5,1)node[right](c){C}--(1,1)node[left](d){P}--(0,0);
\draw (0,0)--(0,2)[left]node(e){Q}--(3,2)node[right](f){S}--(3,0);
\draw (0,2)--(1,2.5)node[above](g){R}--(3.5,2.5);
\draw (3,2)--(3.5,2.5)node[right](h){D}--(3.5,1);
\draw (1,2.5)--(1,1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```