# Simple 3d shapes in LaTeX

Tags: 3d

I want to create simple 3d shapes, cubes, cones, cylinders, etc. Which package is optimal for this operation? I have used tikz before, but I do not know how to use it for 3d images. Any recommended ways to do it?

Comment: This seems like a fairly decent start (if not a duplicate): [Drawing simple 3D cylinders in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31548/5764); [3D bodies in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42812/5764)

Comment: For cubes and cuboids, you might want to try this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267982/tikz-easy-drawing-of-cuboids

Comment: Asymptote has a very thorough implementation of 3D graphics.