# How can I make scaling affect TikZ-pics within a tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling, tikz-pic

I want to have "global scaling" in a TikZ picture, which also affects all pics defined within a `tikzpicture` environment. MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]    
        \draw [green] (0,0) rectangle (10,10);
        \tikzset{square/.pic={\draw [red] (0,0) rectangle (10,10);}}
        \draw (0,0) pic {square};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Why does the red square defined in `square` not fit the green square drawn  within the `tikzpicture`? How can I make the scaling global, affecting all pics defined within it? I would like to avoid scaling every `pic` by hand.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

`transform shape` is your friend. Usually, stuff like nodes (and obviously pics) are not scaled. With `transform shape`, you can enforce this. Note that this also scales text.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, transform shape] % <--- Here!  
        \draw [green] (0,0) rectangle (10,10);
        \tikzset{square/.pic={\draw [red] (0,0) rectangle node[midway, transform shape = false] { Foo } (10,10);}} % note the inserted, not transformed text node
        \draw (0,0) pic {square};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I also saw this possibility, but I would like to only scale the coordinates and to keep the text sizes, line thickness etc.

Comment: I edited my answer. You can use `transform shape = false` locally to disable the transformation. I will include a result Image, but i can't do this now. Try it out! This solution seems a bit impractical at first, but just incorporate this option into your styles (if you don't have any, start using them!) and you're fine.

Comment: I just re-read your comment. I'm not sure how you would change *only* the coordinates, i will think about this.
But i must say: this is the wrong approach. Make your shapes/objects the right size from the beginning on. If you need different sizes, use configurable sizes. Scaling is not meant for this kind of stuff.

Comment: I am drawing objects from the real world, so it would be much more handy to use world coordinates and scale/transform them to "page coordinates".